# How to transition to a empty state with UI ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do you transition a ui-router state to be empty on the UI?

The code I'm using to navigate states looks as follows:

```
$state.transitionTo('admin.client.view', { id: item.practiceID });
```

I'm thinking of just hiding everything within my *admin.client.view* state to achieve the desired result however; I think there must be a better way of doing this.

Is there a way to set the state to empty, by doing something similar to the following?

```
$state.transitionTo('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change to a state that you haven't defined, but there's nothing stopping you from defining an empty state:

```
$stateProvider.state('empty', {
  template: '',
  url: '/whatever'
});
```

If you don't want your state to have a url, then I guess you could make it a child state of whatever state has the URL that you want to be displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can define state with url "/"

```
$stateProvider
    .state 'main',
        url: '/',
        controller: ($scope, $state)->
          console.log "root state"
```

Behaviour of this state will be equal to empty state